# calculating ratio on pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe similar to the following.

```
date    mood    count
1/1/16  negative    400
1/1/16  positive    500
3/1/16  negative    200
5/1/16  positive    700
5/1/16  negative    300
```

I want to get the positive/negative ratio in a new column df['ratio'] for each date. If there is one positive or negative count only for a date (for example **3/1/16 does not have any positive count)**, in that case, the ratio for that date should be 'na'.

`Expected output`

```
date    ratio
1/1/16  1.25
3/1/16  na
5/1/16  2.33
```

How can I do this in pandas? Many thanks. FYI: The file is in csv format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot into a temporary DataFrame, then divide `positive` by `negative`:

```
temp = df.pivot(index='date', columns='mood', values='count')
temp
mood    negative  positive
date                      
1/1/16     400.0     500.0
3/1/16     200.0       NaN
5/1/16     300.0     700.0

(temp['positive'] / temp['negative']).rename('ratio').reset_index()         
     date     ratio
0  1/1/16  1.250000
1  3/1/16       NaN
2  5/1/16  2.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `GroupBy.apply` to create the ratios, then we use `drop_duplicates` to keep only one row per ratio:

```
ratios = (
    df.sort_values('mood')
      .groupby('date')['count'].transform(lambda x: x.div(x.shift()).bfill())
)

dfn = df.assign(ratio = df.index.map(ratios))
        .drop_duplicates('ratio').drop(columns=['mood', 'count'])

print(dfn)
     date     ratio
0  1/1/16  1.250000
2  3/1/16       NaN
3  5/1/16  2.333333
```